# How to avoid using setTimeout to wait for Promises to resolve?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I have a subreddit where I want to parse the comments of all the daily threads. To do so, I have to get the thread ids. I am using snoowrap as an api wrapper.

I am having a hard time wrapping my head around the asynchronous nature of node. When I call `subreddit.search({query: 'Daily General Discussion - ' + date})`, I get a Promise.

I then resolve the promise to get the thread id and push it to a new array (I tried saving the value with `arr[i] = a[0].id`, but only the last result was getting stored in my array,  suggesting that Promise.resolve gets called after my for loop).

**How do I stop the rest of my code from executing before the Promise is resolved? Using setTimeout seems inefficient and unreliable since the resolve time can be longer than my setTimeout time.**

The code below works, I just want to avoid using setTimeout.

```
const subreddit = reddit.getSubreddit('subreddit')

let numberOfDaysBack = 50;
let arrIds           = new Array(0);

for (var i = 0; i < numberOfDaysBack; i++) {
  let date        = moment().subtract(0+i, 'days').format('MMMM D, YYYY')
  let dailyThread = subreddit.search({query: 'Daily General Discussion - ' + date})

  Promise.resolve(dailyThread).then(a=>{
    arrIds.push(a[0].id)
  })
}

setTimeout(function(){
  console.log(arrIds)
},1000)

doOtherStuff(arrIds)
```

Comment: @PatrickEvans Can you explicitly spell it out with me with my example? I am currently using `Promise.resolve().then()`

Comment: `The code below works, I just want to avoid using setTimeout.` - wait for the promises to resolve

Comment: @JaromandaX But if I want to use the values in the array for more computation, how do I ensure that the promises are resolved before I execute more code?

Comment: you wait for the promises to resolve using `Promise.all(promises).then(results => { here the results are yours to play with })`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Map the promises into an array and then use `Promise.all()` to run them concurrently. You will get the results in `then` after all the promises are resolved.

```
const subreddit = reddit.getSubreddit('subreddit')

let numberOfDaysBack = 50
let arrIds

let promises = Array(numberOfDaysBack)
  .fill()
  .map((_, i) => {
    let date        = moment().subtract(0+i, 'days').format('MMMM D, YYYY')
    let dailyThread = subreddit.search({query: 'Daily General Discussion - ' + date})
    return dailyThread
  })

Promise
  .all(promises)
  .then(results => {
    arrIds = results.map(result => result.id)
    doOtherStuff(arrIds)
  });
```

Comment: Promises are not "run".

Comment: @shawon191 I don't think I can access arrIds outside the scope of the then() callback.

Comment: @Huy no you can't. That's not how promise is designed. You simply have to `doOtherStuff(arrIds)` in `then`. (answer updated)

Comment: @shawon191 Promises are just result values. They don't *do* anything. They can be observed, they can be awaited. That some some asynchronous actions run concurrently is because they were started at the same time - independently, not sequentially - and that they return promises or that those are used in `Promise.all` doesn't matter at all.

Comment: @Bergi what I meant was combine the action of mapping over an array and then use `Promise.all` to achieve concurrency. While the `Promise.all` doesn't matter in concurrency it is necessary in this scenario to receive the received values in proper order. The non-concurrent option would be to add the new task in loop sequentially by adding to `then`.
While I understand what you meant by `Promise` are not 'run', I just find it convenient to use the term, as it is the means to manage running async tasks.

Comment: No, that's exactly the problem, the term "run" evokes misconceptions. Promises are not tasks, they're the tasks's results. You cannot use promises to manage async tasks (such as running them in order or even multiple times), you have to do that by function calls and use promises only for managing the flow of result values.

Answer (score 1):

Store all of your promises in an array, and then use [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all):

```
const subreddit = reddit.getSubreddit('subreddit')

let numberOfDaysBack = 50;
let idPromises       = [];

for (var i = 0; i < numberOfDaysBack; i++) {
  let date        = moment().subtract(i, 'days').format('MMMM D, YYYY')
  let dailyThread = subreddit.search({query: 'Daily General Discussion - ' + date})
  idPromises.push(dailyThread.then(a => a[0].id));
}

Promise.all(idPromises).then(arrIds => {
  console.log(arrIds)
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Promise.all() in this type of use case where you have to create a list of promises and wait for all of them to finish.

```
const subreddit = reddit.getSubreddit('subreddit');

const numberOfDaysBack = 50;
const arrIds = new Array(0);
const promises = [];

for (var i = 0; i < numberOfDaysBack; i++) {
  const date = moment().subtract(0+i, 'days').format('MMMM D, YYYY');
  const dailyThread = subreddit.search({query: 'Daily General Discussion - ' + date});

  promises.push(dailyThread);
}

Promise.all(promises).then(function(results){
  results.forEach(function(a){
    arrayIds.push(a[0].id);
  });

  console.log(arrayIds);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `subreddit.search` returns a Promise

```
const subreddit = reddit.getSubreddit('subreddit')

let numberOfDaysBack = 50;

Promise.all(Array.fill(numberOfDaysBack).map((unused, i) => {
    let date        = moment().subtract(0+i, 'days').format('MMMM D, YYYY')
    return subreddit.search({query: 'Daily General Discussion - ' + date}).then(a => a[0].id);
})).then(results => {
    // here results is the array of "a[0].id"
});
// out here, don't expect to access results without using kludges
// so do it all in the `.then`
```

Comment: I see. Thank you for the explanation, I was hoping to be able to access results outside of the then() block, but it doesn't look like it's possible.